# new and old usage in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Can anybody please tell me what is wring with the following code

```
create trigger salary_chk before update on employees for each row
when (employee_id>0)
declare
  begin
    if(new.salary>old.salary*1.2)
      signal 'You cannot do this';
    end if;
  end;
/
```

I get the following error

```
Error report:
ORA-04076: invalid NEW or OLD specification
04076. 00000 -  "invalid NEW or OLD specification"
*Cause:    An invalid NEW or OLD specification was given for a column.
*Action:   Re-specify the column using the correct NEW or OLD specification.
```

Comment: i think you are missing the colon, try  :new.salary > :old.salary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create trigger salary_chk 
before update 
on employees 
for each row
when (new.employee_id > 0) -- missing new
  begin
    if( :new.salary > :old.salary*1.2) -- Missing colons
    then -- Missing then
      dbms_alert.signal('my_alert', 'You Cannot Do this');
    end if;
  end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create trigger salary_chk before update on employees for each row
when (:new.employee_id>0)
declare
  old integer = :old.salary * 1.2;

  begin
    if(:new.salary>old)
      signal 'You cannot do this';
    end if;
  end;
```

Try this out. I can't see any other reason why it shouldn't be working since it's PL/SQL

Comment: The WHEN clause doesn't use the `:`. Don't ask me why.